# How can I get list of all users reporting to perticular user using UserProfileManager?

Tags: user-profile-service, userprofilemanager

I can see that UserProfileManager class does have a method GetManager() to pull manager from users profile but I don't see any thing which returns list of all users currently reporting to particular user. I am wondering if there is any workaround.

```
SPSite site;
SPWeb web;
SPServiceContext serviceContext;
UserProfileManager profiles;
UserProfile profile;

try
{
  using (site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url))
  {
    using (web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
      serviceContext = SPServiceContext.GetContext(site);
      profiles = new UserProfileManager(serviceContext);

      //Getting the profile of logged in user.
     profile = profiles.GetUserProfile(web.CurrentUser.LoginName);

    //Getting profile of the manager of the logged in user.
    profile = profile.GetManager();
    }
  }
}
catch { }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do indeed have methods for getting manager, peers and direct reports:

```
        // Check whether the user profile and the manager user profile exist, and that they are not                  
        // the same user.            
        if (userProfileManager.UserExists(loginName))
        {
            // Retrieve the user profile.                
            UserProfile userProfile = userProfileManager.GetUserProfile(loginName);  

            // Get the user's multiple levels of managers, peers, and direct reports.                 
            managers = new List<UserProfile>(userProfile.GetManagers());                
            peers = new List<UserProfile>(userProfile.GetPeers());                
            directReports = new List<UserProfile>(userProfile.GetDirectReports());
```

}

Works in 2007, should be same in 2010: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc973103(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: how can get the same in O 365, SPO ?